# A man sitting here or seated here

Tags: participles

What is the difference between the sentences below when the situation  is a state condition.

1. A man is sitting in the Room.
2. A man is seated in the Room

Comment: I don't think there is any difference.

Answer (score 1):

There might be no difference. However, in one interpretation, it's certainly possible for there to be a distinction:

> 1. The man is sitting here.
>    He is voluntarily in the chair and he put himself there. In this exact sentence construction, where *sitting* is uses as a verb rather than an adjective, it is an intransitive verb.
>    Note, too, that the identical sentence could be used with *sitting* in its adjectival sense, where the man's position is being described rather than there being any action.
> 2. The man is seated here.
>    He has been *involuntarily* strapped into the chair (for instance). This is a use of the *transitive* version of the verb. Somebody else has put him into the chair. The transitive use can also be applied to voluntary situations—such as audience members of a play being seated by ushers.
>    It's also possible for *seated* to be taken adjectivally rather than verbally—although it wouldn't be as common.

In short, there can be a difference between *sitting* and *seated* in some contexts. Whether or not there actually is one could only be determined from the particular context.

---

The use of "when the situation is a state condition" in the question implies that it's being used in an adjectival sense. In that case, there really is no difference—unless *seated* is thought to be the state condition that has arisen as a result of the *transitive* use of the verb. The immediate description would be the same, but the surrounding context would be different.